# Definition of a port's "function" for the acceptance criteria: "measurement" vs. "command and control"?

Tags: compliance

I can't find any written definition for selecting the "Function" of a port in Compliance standards like 60255-26 Table 23. The definition determines whether it must stay within spec during transients.  If a device is labeled as "Measurement", it can deviate from its spec if it self-recovers.  If it is "Command and control", it must not.

I have an analog input that I want to label as "Measurement" so that I don't have to add cost to filter the transients in that device.  Its data is cleaned up by the user *externally* to remove transient excursions, then used as command inputs to the user's external PID.  The fact that it is used as command inputs to the PID makes it sound like "Command and Control" data, so the user is concerned that my analog input function must be labeled as "Command and Control".  But the data my device provides has been processed in between, making it sort of different data.  I'd like to say it is Measurement out of my device, and the user turns the same datastream into "Command and Control" by signal conditioning before they use it in their PID.

I've heard lots of opinions on why it makes sense one way or the other.  But I'm looking for something stronger than opinion, and I can't find it when searching any standards I've read so far.  So I have a two-part question: **What is the definition of the "Measurement" function as used in 60255-26; and can a user be compliant if they are cleaning up "Measurement" data before using it for as Command Inputs to their PID?**  (I assume PID Command Inputs = Command & Control.)

Comment: if in doubt, common sense presumably applies.

Comment: I love the idea of that.  Unfortunately, common sense doesn't seem to reign in the litigation world.  I've heard only know if you "got Compliance right" when someone takes your product to court....

Comment: which is more likely and better for you: someone goes to court and claims that your command and control port is actually a measurement port; the judge agrees; measurement ports have looser regulations, which you meet. Or:  someone goes to court and claims that your command and control port is actually a command and control port; the judge agrees; your port doesn't meet the regulations for command and control ports.

Comment: I don't know what 60255-26 Table 23 is, as I don't have that standard, but the overall standard is for "measuring relays and protection equipment". I assume that *in the context of a measuring relay* (whatever that is) the difference between a measurement port and a C&C port is fairly well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer is to **declare and defend** the product's capabilities to meet the standard one is claiming.  In this case, I must state whether to claim the device is able to stand up to the Command & Control threshold, or whether users should only expect a Measurement-level of performance.  Then my tests substantiate the claim.  Users then learn from my written specification what I promise and then set up/compensate their overall system accordingly.